# Infragistics WebScheduleInfo Sample code

Tags: deployment, infragistics, readonly

I am working with Infragistics35.WebUI.WebSchedule.v8.2.  I am not seeing any good documentation on this on the Infragistics Web site.  Does anyone have any sample code I could see?  I am trying to create a week view of the calendar.  One that "Admins" can edit and the rest of the users can only view.  I would love to have a different dblclick event fire based on role, so that a read only version of the activity would show for non admins.  Is that possible?  I'm just using an access db on the site in the App_Data directory.  I really just needed (I thought) an out of the box solution.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

The experience I have had with the WebSchedule (linked to WebMonth, WebWeek and WebDay) is to base access to editing based on permissions that would need to be referenced when the page is loaded. When the user clicks on the cell perform a method that checks the security level and adjust fields and such to appropriate levels (enabled/disabled) based on their level. This can be done through userlogins if the logins are controls through the database or use Membership to control this.